# vim regex with meta-characters

Tags: regex, vim

I have the following in a text file:

```
This is some text for cv_1 for example
This is some text for cv_001 for example
This is some text for cv_15 for example
```

I am trying to use regex `cv_.*?\s` to match `cv_1`, `cv_001`, `cv_15` in the text. I know that the regex works. However, it doesn't match anything when I try it in Vim.

Do we need to do something special in Vim?

Comment: Easy way to see what's wrong is to turn on `:set incsearch`. You'd see the search suddenly fail to match when entering the question mark.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The non-greedy character `?` doesn't work in Vim; you should use:

```
cv_.\{-}\s
```

...instead of:

```
cv_.*?\s
```

Here's a quick reference for matching:

```
     * (0 or more) greedy matching
    \+ (1 or more) greedy matching
  \{-} (0 or more) non-greedy matching
\{-n,} (at least n) non-greedy matching
```

Comment: `%s/cv_.\{-}\ze\s/replacement/g`

Comment: `\ze` ends the match before the whitespace character so it doesn't get replaced

Comment: This worked great why doesn't the ? mark work in vim? That seems odd to me.

Answer (score 5):

vim's regex syntax is a little different -- what you're looking for is

```
cv_.\{-}\s
```

(the `\{-}` being the vim equivalent of perl's `*?`, i.e., non-greedy 0-or-more).  See [here](https://www.vimregex.com) for a good tutorial on vim's regular expressions.